# Sending Django query to Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I need to reference a database where I grab all the data that match a parameter which is inputted by the user. There can be up to 10 objects in the call and I need to grab multiple values from those objects. Is there a way I can send a filtered query to ajax and display the values?

Ajax:

```
<script>
  $("#id_iden").on('change', function(){
    if ($(this).val() !== ""){
      var qn = $(this).val()
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ship/ajax-shipping/",
        data: { 'quote': qn },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          if (data.i){ #tried i.item and i[0[
            $("#id_item").val(data.jax)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  })
  </script>
```

View:

```
def ajax_shipping(request):
    id_quote = request.GET.get('quote', None)
    quote = HomeTable.objects.filter(id=id_quote).values_list('quote_num_id', flat=True)
    items = IItemDetails.objects.filter(quote_num_id=quote).values_list('item', 'quan', 'shipped')
   data = {
        'i' : items,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Is there a way I can show the values of a query with ajax? Thanks!

Comment: What problems are you having with this code?

Comment: I'm not getting any output at all, I know the data is there and it's sending, but nothing is showing on the webpage.

Comment: Please edit your question (title and description) to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the response in your browser's debugger ?

Comment: Yes, it is getting the right input from the user, but it doesn't seem to be sending anything back to the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I just had an error in my URLs that wasn't sending the ajax call to the right place. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: please consider checking my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65392701/how-to-access-queryset-returned-to-template-by-ajax-response-django)